# Why does the addition operator append hash key-value pairs?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to programming and trying to make sense of why an operator almost always use for addition, appends a hash key-value pair in Ruby.

The following code snippet is from the Pragmatic Studio Ruby course:

```
letters = {"c" => 3, "e" => 1, "l" => 1, "n" => 1, "t" => 1, "x" => 8, "y" => 4}
point_totals = Hash.new(0)

"excellently".each_char do |char|
    point_totals[char] += letters[char]
end

puts point_totals
puts point_totals.values.reduce(0, :+)
```

**Output**

```
{"e"=>3, "x"=>8, "c"=>3, "l"=>3, "n"=>1, "t"=>1, "y"=>4}
23
```

Why does the language use `+=` instead of `<<`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `+=` because you are adding the value of `letters[char]` to `points_total[char]`

`<<` is used for appending to an array.

Comment: `<<` also appends to a `String`

Comment: So basically, this is like a `map` method for strings?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `map` is used when you want to apply a function on every element and generate a new array. Your code basically calculates the total points for each character in your string.

Comment: @rohit89 The `fix << num` method of Fixnum shifts left num positions (or right if num is negative) in binary. So `2<<3` is  `10`(binary) with 3 zero's attached, 16 in decimal. My point is: "<< is used for appending to an array." is not false, but inaccurate.

Comment: @steenslag: It's appending zeroes to an array of bits ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're not appending a key-value pair, you're incrementing the value associated with the `char` key in the `points_total` hash.